# Prevent assets/stylesheets loading into heroku application

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I currently have an application deployed here: https://morning-shelf-1378.herokuapp.com/job-fairs

As you can see it has combined the style-sheets from ActiveAdmin assets/stylesheets into the application causing the font to be underlined etc. when I only want it to be displayed on https://morning-shelf-1378.herokuapp.com/admin/.

Is there a way to specify the stylesheets from ActiveAdmin to not be displayed by default? When I deploy locally everything seems to be fine.

```
Rails.application.configure do

 config.cache_classes = true

 config.eager_load = true

 config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
 config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

 config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

 config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

 config.assets.compile = false

 config.assets.digest = true

 config.log_level = :debug
 config.i18n.fallbacks = true


 config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

 config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

 config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` file you need to remove this line

```
 *= require_tree .
```

or
move your `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss` and `app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js.coffee` files into `vendor/assets/stylesheets/` and`vendor/assets/javascripts` directory

or comment this lines in `production.rb` file

```
 # config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
 # config.assets.compile = false
 # config.assets.digest = true
```

Comment: yep did that the issue is that it still combines the stylesheet in heroku

Comment: Deploying locally is fine, it's just when I need to deploy on heroku I get a problem, might be an issue with the production.rb file?

Comment: add your `production.rb` file

Comment: Not much luck currently, Ill try experimenting with the config file but if anyone has an idea feel free to tell me.